# Загрузка git по tags

Tags: git, bitbucket

У меня есть репозиторий на битбакете. Там есть директория, в которой очень много веток, при этом в веб версии есть вкладка "теги". Я сделал клон основной папки, по ссылке на битбакете, но мне нужно именно этой папки с обозначением "2.0" [image: гит по версии, а не по ветке]" Как мне на ПК загрузить это?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git checkout tags/<tag_name> -b <branch_name>
```

Вы создадите ветку от тегированного коммита и перейдете к нему.

```
git checkout tags/<tag_name>
```

Вы перейдет на коммит tag и следующий коммит.

Чтобы смотреть в ветки одновременно...git из коробки так не умеет, но можно сделать так

Создаете 2 папки. В первой и второй делаете git clone. В каждой папке будет не связанные друг с другом репозитории, которые привязаны к одному серверу.

В первой папке делаете `git checkout tags/2.0 -b test` Во второй ничего не произойдет(физически это другой репозиторий). Во втором можете делать checkout куда хотите, ничего не изменится.

Таким образом вы можете локально смотреть в 2 ветки.

Comment: Создам ветку локально, или удалённо?

Comment: @Igor-Potapov пока не сделаете push - локально.

Comment: Спасибо, я создал ветку и перешел к ней, а как теперь с битбакета загрузить файлы которые обозначены тегом 2.0, как на моём скриншоте?

Comment: @Igor-Potapov вы уже стоите на этой ветке. Данная ветка - это уже скачанные файлы. Тобишь вы перешли к версии, которая была отмечена тегом.

Comment: хм, я новичок в гите, но когда я делаю клон, как я понимаю,копируются папки с одной ветки "мастер" а не сразу всё, верно? Я не понимаю как на ПК мне отследить какие файлы относятся к мастеру, а какие к тегу 2.0?

Comment: Когда вы делаете clone, по дефолту подтягивается все, просто то, с чем вы еще локально не работаете, лежит в origin, а локально в local(названия могу попутать, но суть такая)

Тобишь при clone вы получаете полную копию репы в момент на данный момент. 
Про вторую часть не понял. Если файлы лежит в ветке, значит он в ней находится. Его версия. Если вы его не видите, значит он не используется в этой ветке.

Comment: @Igor-Potapov git - не хранилище с подпапками. Это система, которая показывает дерево работы с файлами, их версии.

Представьте 3 дороги, которые выходят из одной. Вы катите бочку. 
И поехав по разной дороге с бочкой может пройзойти что угодно(что вы хотите). Она может вообще исчезнуть. Вот все проделанный операции на каждой из веток - это своя версия событий. 
Когда вы захотите вернуться на одну дорогу(а очевидно бочка одна), вам надо решить, что мы считаем с ней на самом деле произошло(либо одна из 3 дорого, либо вообще 4 вариант) на основе истории изменений.

Comment: @Igor-Potapov историю изменений файла можно посмотреть. Посмотреть, в какой ветку что происходило - можно в конечной точке, когда сольете вашу под ветку в мастер. Будет видна история изменений и там по ветка можно отследить откуда из какой ветки пришло изменение.

Comment: @Igor-Potapov подробнее предлагаю уже самому капнуть в работу гита. 

Если вам ответ помог, отметьте его ответом на вопрос, чтобы другие пользователя могли увидеть, что есть ответ(галочка у вопроса)

Comment: @Igor-Potapov галочка у ответа

Comment: Концепцию гита я понимаю, на битбакете при выборе ветки, отображается её содержимое, при выборе другой ветки, другое содержимое. Но после клона я на пк вижу одну локальную папку. Я думал, что можно для каждой ветки загружать отдельно файлы, которые будут доступны локально. Я Ваш ответ отмечу, но локально добраться к файлу с версией 2.0 я так и не понял как. Именно локально через файловый менеджер (у меня убунту).

Comment: @Igor-Potapov в таком случае вам надо склонировать проект в отдельную папку и сделать checkout там. Тогда вы сможете смотреть на 2 ветки. 

По факту у вас будет 2 репозитория, каждый из которых смотрит на свою ветку.

Comment: Я перешел в директорию: `it@Igor:~/bitbucket/automation$` и выполнил `git checkout tags/2.0 -b test` таким образом у меня должна появиться директория "test" в папке automation?

Comment: Создаете 2 папки.
В первой и второй делаете git clone
В каждой папке будет не связанные друг с другом репозитории, которые привязаны к одному серверу.
В первой папке делаете git checkout tags/2.0 -b test
Во второй ничего не произойдет(физически это другой репозиторий). Во втором можете делать checkout куда хотите, ничего не изменится.

Comment: Спасибо! Вы самый мощный!